# model a shape something like a raspberry

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

[image: beans]

I am trying to build something like this. Is there a nice way without just snapping spheres to vertices? It could be interesting to look at using the Fibonacci sequence also to distribute the spheres.

Comment: I would just sculpt this thing as every ball is quite irregular. It's also an easy shape to sculpt.

Comment: thanks jerry but i am aiming for the pure form of this i guess so the spheres would be more regular. i dont want to get lost in the sculpting .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at **[Dupliverts](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/duplication/dupliverts.html)**, that allows the duplication of a base object at the location of the vertices of a mesh. In other words, when using DupliVerts on a mesh, an instance of the base object is placed on every vertex of the mesh.

Or try the **[Tissue add-on](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue)** by [Alessandro Zomparelli](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue/wiki)

It allows you to copy a selected object (Component) on the faces of the active object (Generator), adapting its bounding box to the shape of quad-faces.

[image]

Thread on Blenderartists.org with more examples [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?375378-tissue-by-Alessandro-Zomparelli)

Comment: the addon you linked would make a nice solution , but you should add an example ( pics and steps ) to make it more useful .

Comment: it looks real interesting thanks for the tip .

Comment: both the dupliverts and the tissue addon looking like nice ways to go . am having problems with the add on though . got it downloaded and running but the tesallatte button is not highlighted ready to use . the other buttons in the addon are working just not the one i need . any ideas . thanks

Comment: ah ok i got it . managed to find this little vid to see what i was doing wrong 
https://vimeo.com/132720942. thanks again it looks great

Comment: dupliverts are amazing . dont know how i missed them so long . really thanks for the great ideas. getting close to what i am trying to build now . thanks

Comment: @segg if this answer answers our question you can mark it as accepted ( the check mark on the left )